cv.VideoWriter genera un archivo no reproducible al intentar convertir un video en color a escala de grises
Estoy aprendiendo a usar OPENCV-PYTHON recientemente estaba tratando de convertir un video de RGB a escala de GRISES pero el video se guarda con 258bytes y es un archivo sin formato
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


video = cv.VideoCapture('videos/prueba.mp4')
alto = int(video.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))
ancho = int(video.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
fourcc = cv.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v')
record = cv.VideoWriter('video_esc_grises.mp4',fourcc,25.0,(ancho,alto))

while video.isOpened():
    ret,frame1 = video.read()
    if not ret: 
        break
    grises = cv.cvtColor(frame1,cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    record.write(grises)   
    cv.imshow('video',grises)
    #if cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'): break

video.release()
record.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()


De la documentación oficial de OpenCV (traducción libre):

cv.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize[, isColor]) -> <objeto VideoWriter>

Parámetros:

...
isColor: Si no es cero, el codificador esperará y codificará fotogramas en color, en caso contrario trabajará con fotogramas en escala de grises.




El parámetro isColor es opcional y es True/1 por defecto. Si no lo especificas explícitamente el códec esperará frames en color e intentará generar un vídeo en color.
Por lo tanto, debería ser:
record = cv.VideoWriter('video_esc_grises.mp4', fourcc, 25.0, (ancho,alto), False)

Otra opción es haciendo uso del argumento params de la otra forma de la función:

cv.VideoWriter(filename, fourcc, fps, frameSize, params) -> <objeto VideoWriter>

params permite pasar parámetros extra para el códec
especificándolos como parejas de la forma:
(paramId_1, paramValue_1, paramId_2, paramValue_2, ... .)

ver cv::VideoWriterProperties



record = cv.VideoWriter(
    'video_esc_grises.mp4',
    fourcc,
    25.0,
    (ancho, alto),
    (cv.VIDEOWRITER_PROP_IS_COLOR, 0)
)

Aunque es complicarse a no ser que eventualmente usamos params para pasar otros parámetros extra al códec.

muchas gracias me fue muy util.

Hola buenas como te ha respondido te falta poner detrás del alto y el ancho otra variable y si quieres ver el resultado te recomiendo la web web video en escala de grises


Saludos, el código siempre debe ir como texto, recuerda solo utilizar imagenes cuando sea absolutamente necesario. ;)

Muchas Gracias me fui muy util.
